# Recent Field Calculation - Storage Location

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am wondering where specifically (directory-wise) QGIS is storing the "Recent (fieldcalc)" expressions within the Field Calculator. I'd really like to be able to see the entirety of my history or quickly access it for record keeping purposes, and I can't seem to find this anywhere online already. I've also done a rudimentary search of the QGIS folder saved on my machine, but no luck there either.

I am working with Desktop version 3.24.1, not sure if that impacts anything but definitely worth mentioning.

Comment: If you open/use Field Calculator through the processing toolbox you can access the history with Ctrl+Alt+H

Answer (score 0):

File location:

```
%AppData%\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3.ini
```

and the section is:

```
[expressions]
```

Since the file is INI format, [configparser — Configuration file parser - Python 3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) can be used to parse it, and the `expressions` section looks like [shlex — Simple lexical analysis - Python 3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) can be used for parsing.

```py
import configparser
import os
import shlex

qgis_ini = os.path.join(os.environ['appdata'], "QGIS",  "QGIS3", "profiles",
                        "default", "QGIS", "QGIS3.ini")

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(qgis_ini)
exps_str = config.get('expressions', r'recent\fieldcalc')
exps = shlex.split(exps_str)

for exp in exps:
    print("\r\n" + "-"*40)
    print(exp.replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n")[:-1])
```